# Overriding "Text" property of a control extended from Button using C#

Tags: c#, overriding, extend, asp.net-webcontrol

I'm having a problem extending the standard WebControls.Button control. I need to override the text property, but I receive the error message:

> cannot override inhereted member 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.Text.get' because it is not marked virtual, abstract or override

I used the following code for a LinkButton, and that worked perfectly:

```
public class IconLinkButton : LinkButton
{
    private string _icon = "";
    public string Icon
    {
        get
        {
            return _icon;
        }
        set
        {
            _icon = value;
        }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "<i class=\""+Icon+"\"></i> " + base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

However, doing the same thing for a standard Button kicks up the error I described above.

```
public class IconButton : Button
{
    private string _icon = "";
    public string Icon
    {
        get
        {
            return _icon;
        }
        set
        {
            _icon = value;
        }
    }

    public virtual string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return "<i class=\"" + Icon + "\"></i> " + base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `LinkButton` has a `virtual` Text property.. whilst `Button` does not.

You can hide the base functionality entirely by using `new`:

```
public class IconButton : Button {
    public new string Text {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Using `new` hides the inherited member completely.

Comment: Will `base.Text` return the parents' `Text` property or does it override it with its own as well?

Comment: It will function as you expect.. since in your original you are just using it as a proxy to the underlying inherited property anyway.

Comment: Thanks Simon, this has worked perfectly and now that you've explained it, it makes sense! Will accept answer as soon as I'm able to :)

Comment: Keep in mind this method won't be *virtual*.  If you have `Button b = new IconButton();`, it will no longer work.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I had considered that before answering, however given that it is WebForms and the OP wasn't sure how to even do this.. it was unlikely that was a use case.